# How can i set a new color with getRGB

Tags: java, colors, rgb

I want to create a new color since when i use .getRGB() it works perfectly but thee's only few colors registered.

This is my code which it worked with the color blue and yellow:

```
if (!convergence(z0)){
                        pixels[(i*Y + j)] = Color.yellow.getRGB();
                    }
                    else{
                        pixels[i*Y + j] = Color.blue.getRGB();
                    }

                }
        }
        BufferedImage pixelImage = new BufferedImage(X, Y, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);    
        pixelImage.setRGB(0, 0, X, Y, pixels, 0, X);
```

How can i add new color? 
Thank you.

Comment: Color myColor = new Color(r,g,b);

Answer (score 1):

You can't. At least not so you could do something like `Color.THE_COLOR_OF_HER_HAIR`.

However nothing stops you from creating constants in a class of your own, e.g.

```
public class MyColors {
    public final static Color THE_COLOUR_OF_HER_EYES = Color.GREEN;
    public final static Color THE_COLOUR_OF_HER_HAIR = new Color(255,74,0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Color myCustomColor = new Color(r, g, b);`

Or with transparency:

`Color myCustomColor = new Color(r, g, b, a);`

There are great resources online for finding a color's rgb value.